# How can a bright blue spaceship have "Stealth technology"?

Tags: babylon-5

In Babylon 5, during the Earth-Minbari war, the Earthers could never hit the Minbari ships because, according to Sheridan they had "some kind of stealth technology".

But the Minbari warships are big and bright blue! And never shown to be particularly agile.  How can they be stealthy? Even if they can somehow be able to fool the scanners or the radar or whatever they have, couldn't the Earth missiles just be given cameras and be programmed to head for the big blue thing?

Comment: And that, kids, is how we accidentally destroyed the Hubble.

Comment: “Stealth technology”, at least in military context, is more about stealth from equipment like radars, rather than stealth from the eye.

Comment: Modern stealth fighters are also quite visible to the naked eye, loud, and not that maneuverable either. Doesn't help when your seeker warhead can't lock on to it. ;-) @suchiuomizu: The moment someone creates a proper *visual* tracking device, though... ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was [addressed by JMS](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/023.html).

> Yes, **you can go in and shoot at a Minbari *cruiser* visually...but the reality is that any long-range weapon will be intercepted by targeting fire, and if you get up real close and personal...well, actually, you *can't* get up real close and personal** because, as Mitchell learned in "Sky," you get shot by the fighters.
> What the fighters tend to remain engaged with are the **Minbari fighters, which are *incredibly* fast...much too fast to target visually.**
>
> And believe me, as Sheridan stated, Earth's been *trying* to break the stealth tech for a while, just hasn't been able to.

Note that Minbari ships seem to *actively resist* weapons locking onto them by messing with the enemy's targeting system. This can be turned on and off.

> "One problem during the war was that none of our weapon systems
> could lock on to the Minbari vessels. **They use some kind of stealth technology we were never able to break. So how come all of a sudden
> we can track them?**"